# VueJS parent mouseover event masking child mouseover event

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, event-handling

I am using VueJS and trying to fire a mouseover event on two  elements, one a child element of the other.

I am unable to get the child mouseover event to fire. It appears the parent element is "covering" the child div and only the parent mouseover event is registered.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hoverTarget: 'none'
  },
  methods: {
    parentHover: function() {
      this.hoverTarget = 'parent'
    },
    childHover: function() {
      this.hoverTarget = 'child'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}

#child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div id='parent' @mouseover="parentHover">
    <div id='child' @mouseover="childHover">

    </div>
  </div>
  {{ hoverTarget }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additionally, you could abbreviate this, using an [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), to `@mouseover.stop="childHover"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <div id='app'>
  <div id='parent' @mouseover="parentHover">
    <div id='child' @mouseover="childHover">

    </div>
  </div>
  {{ hoverTarget }}
</div>
```

This is happening because of the **event bubbling** principal

> When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it,
>   then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

that means `childHover` handler will get executed and immediately after it 
the `parentHover` will be executed making the child execution invisible.

to solve your problem you can use `event.stopPropagation()` method of the event to make sure no bubbling happens from child to parent.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hoverTarget: 'none'
  },
  methods: {
    parentHover: function() {
      this.hoverTarget = 'parent'
    },
    childHover: function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation()
      this.hoverTarget = 'child'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This works if I remove the 'event' function parameter. Thank you!

Comment: the idea is to stop event propogation. every event handler will give you access to the event that was fired. you just have to stop the propogation

Answer (score 0):

CSS `:has` has pretty good support (no Firefox, but everywhere else is good, as of 2-23).

`:has` allows you to target an element that meets any arbitrary conditions about its own children.

```
#parent:not(:has(#child:hover)):hover { ... }
```